# How to give between symbols in an equation in Latex

Tags: spacing

```
\begin{equation}
 k = \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}[sin\theta cos\phi  cos\theta sin\phi  cos\theta]
\end{equation}
```

Now I want to give space between "sin\theta cos\phi" and "cos\theta sin\phi".

Can anyone suggest me how it can be done?

Answer (score 2):

You have several alternatives for doing that. First of all, you should use `\cos` instead of just writing `cos`. Then, for spaces, you could add a space using `\,` or `\;` or `\quad` or `\qquad` (increasing spacing). See the example below.

```
\begin{equation}
    k = \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda}[\sin\theta \,\cos\phi \; \cos\theta \quad \sin\phi \qquad \cos\theta]
\end{equation}
```